# Trying to find the meaning of an Italian figure of speech - idiom

Tags: meaning

I read an article today about the Italian actress Anna Magnani, and the director Roberto Rossellini said that " She was born with her liver in her teeth." What does that mean?

Comment: The exact expression appears to be “She was born carrying her liver in her teeth". https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0536167/bio - https://www.theneweuropean.co.uk/brexit-news/europe-news/great-european-lives-anna-magnani-93952

Comment: Do I understand correctly? The article gave the phrase in English?

Comment: yes..I read the phrase in English and was wondering if it was the translation of an Italian saying. In context it seems to mean she was a tough woman or someone to be reckoned with? ... but I was wondering if there was more to it or more of an exact meaning.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question seems to be more about English language rather than Italian Language

Comment: Personally, as a native Italian this doesn't sound as the translation of an Italian idiom (and I'm not sure what they meant in English either). Is there a way to understand whether Rossellini was speaking in English or in Italian (and the interviewer translated his words)?

Comment: thanks everybody...maybe it was just a Rossellini-ism.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not an idiomatic sentence altough you can guess the meaning: I think Rossellini meant she used to speak harshly, using bitter words. The liver is where the bile is produced and in Italian we use the word "_fiele_" (bile) to figuratively indicate something done with bitter, harsh or hurtful intentions (I think English has the expression "to spit bile", which is used in the same way)

Comment: thanks again secan....that makes perfect sense and adds a bit more specificity to his saying!